# How to get the payment transaction of a subscription just created through Recurly's Ruby API?

Tags: ruby, recurly

If a subscription is created with

```
recurly_subscription = Recurly::Subscription.create!( ... )
```

the corresponding invoice can be retrieved with

```
recurly_subscription.invoice
```

But how to retrieve the corresponding payment transaction?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
s = Recurly::Subscription.first
s.invoice.transactions
```